# How to fix flare in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, lighting

I have a simple sun flare that I would like to appear on my directional light (sun). However I cannot see the flare, I have tried setting the ignore layers to everything and checked and double checked that there is a flare layer on my camera. The light is also rotating constantly as I have a day/night cycle too if that means anything for the flare... Anyway, could someone show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the flare as-

Select light(in the Game)-> Go to add component-> Select Effects-> Select Lens Flare
Now you will get Flare's field, where you can attach your Sun Flare by simply select the flare that you want.
In this you can also set the size of flare.

Comment: I have done that already, but it just won't show up...

Comment: I have draw halo on an I can see that moving perfectly, but I can't see my flare.

Comment: Ohh now I got why you facing this problem I guess you didn't enable the Flare option just next to your game window..... Didn't...? Do that and let me know.

Comment: Do you mean the little sun like icon or the square with the landscape? Either way I tried both, neither worked.

Comment: Yeah its just next to the the game window and it doesn't have any icon. There is a small arrow sign onto which you will click then you will find the check box with the name flare then you can enable that option then flare will be showing in your game.

Comment: And the sun like icon is for light not for lens flare. Once you do that as I suggested you and then let me know otherwise I will send snapshots.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure, could you send some screenshots?

Comment: Yeah sure I will send but here I don't know how to attach image files... If you know then let me know I will do exactly like that.

Comment: Go to imgur.com, you can upload images there and just send the link here.

Comment: http://imgur.com/HI61jqC Here you go....you can enable the flare from there. When you will be sorted out your problem then let me know. ;)

Comment: Ah yes, I thought it was that, I do have that enabled, but there is still no flare.

Comment: Ohh buddy then you should try it once again and now do check all the properties of flare like size, brightness, direction etc because it is may be showing but by the cause of size or anything else it is not being seen so I guess you ought to do it once again and let me know. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LensFlare.html you can refer this too. Best Luck

Comment: My reputation is not above 50 that is why I cant comment on your new answer but if my answer and replies are helpful for you please up vote and you can also give your own question's answer here it is useful for you and other's as well.

Comment: And I told you to attach your lens flare component in my first answer that you have to select light and all that I wrote there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out now, just had to add a Lens Flare component to my directional light, didn't realise you had to do that!

Comment: M happy that you have sorted out your problem ;)